# Converting array of objects into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my initial array:

```
[ 
   { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'pos',
    code: 'pos123',
    appCode: 22,
   },
  { 
    id: 2,
    name: 'tailor',
    code: 'tailor123',
    appCode: 21,
  } 
]
```

My desired output:

```
{
   pos123: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'pos',
    code: 'pos123',
    appCode: 22,
  },
  tailor123: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tailor',
    code: 'tailor123',
    appCode: 21,
  },
}
```

I tried doing this with `map`, but I couldn't figure it out. Should I be using `reduce` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is not an array - it's an object, so you have to use `reduce`. You can only use `map` to turn X number of items in an array into X number of items in another array.

```js
const input=[{id:1,name:'pos',code:'pos123',appCode:22,},{id:2,name:'tailor',code:'tailor123',appCode:21,}]
const output = input.reduce((a, obj) => {
  a[obj.code] = obj;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forget to put, i also need code object inside main object!

Comment: Edited. (Try to make sure you post your *actual* desired output in questions the first time)

Comment: `obj.code` is redundantly included in the new objects

Comment: @KooiInc It was originally excluded, but OP asked for it, see comment above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` mapping your array to expected shape of keys and values. Try:

```js
let array = [ 
   { 
    id: 1,
    name: 'pos',
    code: 'pos123',
    appCode: 22,
   },
  { 
    id: 2,
    name: 'tailor',
    code: 'tailor123',
    appCode: 21,
  } 
];

let output = Object.assign(...array.map(x => ({ [x.code]: x })));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: you are putting appCode, name static, but my json contains more than 20 datas?

Comment: @MohamedSameer updated, you can use destructuring here

Comment: Sorry, i forget to put, i also need code object inside main object!

Comment: @MohamedSameer okay, so it's easier. Please modify your original post

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourArray = [ 
 { 
  id: 1,
  name: 'pos',
  code: 'pos123',
  appCode: 22,
  },
 {  
  id: 2,
  name: 'tailor',
  code: 'tailor123',
  appCode: 21,
 } 
];

//this is what you required
var output =  yourArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[obj.code] =item;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array reduce function

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'pos',
    code: 'pos123',
    appCode: 22,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tailor',
    code: 'tailor123',
    appCode: 21,
  }
]

var modData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  //acc is the empty array passed as argument
  // if empty array does not have a property pos123 or so 
  // create a key by this name
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(curr.code)) {
    // then add property to it
    acc[curr.code] = {
      id: curr.id,
      name: curr.name,
      appCode: curr.appCode
    }
  }

  return acc;

}, {})

console.log(modData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loop you can do this.

```js
const resp = [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: 'pos',
    code: 'pos123',
    appCode: 22,
   },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'tailor',
    code: 'tailor123',
    appCode: 21,
  }
]

let res = {};

for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
  res[resp[i]['code']] = {
    id: resp[i]['id'],
    name: resp[i]['name'],
    appCode: resp[i]['appCode'],
    code: resp[i]['code']
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the other solutions include 'code'-property in the resulting object. This one doesn't

```js
const test = [ 
  { 
   id: 1,
   name: 'pos',
   code: 'pos123',
   appCode: 22,
  }, { 
   id: 2,
   name: 'tailor',
   code: 'tailor123',
   appCode: 21,
  } 
];
const test2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test));
const result = document.querySelector("#result");

result.textContent = "**No redundancy\n" + JSON.stringify(
  test.reduce( (newObj, el) => 
    (newObj[el.code] = delete el.code && el) && newObj, {} 
  ), null, " ");

// alternative
result.textContent += "\n\n**Alternative\n" + JSON.stringify(
  test2.reduce( (newObj, el) => (newObj[el.code] = el) && newObj, {}
  ), null, " ");
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```